# SharePoint online plan 1 Vs SPO K

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing

In this comparison between Office 365 F3 Suite & Office 365 E1 Suite @ https://www.communicationsquare.com/news/microsoft-365-f1-vs-microsoft-365-f3-vs-office-365-f3/, it mentioned that the SharePoint online for E1 will be plan-1 while the SharePoint online for F3 will be SPO K, as follow:-

[image]

so what are the differences between SharePoint online plan 1 & SPO K ?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this article for more information about Plan 1:
[Compare SharePoint Online options](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)

And [this article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/office-365-f3?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) about Office f3:
[image]

Reference:
[Microsoft 365 and Office 365 plan options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options)